# duplicated vertices in mesh generation

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

I want to generate a `MeshRegion` from `ParametricPlot3D`, e.g. the hemisphere
(the `PlotPoints` is used to get small numbers of vertices)

```
g = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}, {θ, 0, π/2},
 {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, PlotPoints -> {4, 4}, MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> Full];
surf = DiscretizeGraphics[Normal@g];
{g, surf}
```

The number of vertices, as you may see is 10, but the generated
`MeshRegion` has 42.

```
MeshCells[surf, 0] // Length
```

Many of vertices are duplicated. In fact they are distinct but their coordinates differ very little:

```
Counts@Round[MeshCoordinates[surf][[All]], .0001]
Counts@Round[MeshCoordinates[surf][[All]], 10.^-16]
```

Is there any way to avoid such duplications?

Comment: @Anjan - how to paste greek letters in the post ? I have searched the forum a bit but did not find.

Comment: It's a plugin. See this https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1044/19742

Comment: it's nice, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Summary**

I find that discretised regions often run into difficulties here (along with the related problem that many of the higher dimensional cells have essentially negligible measure). I know of no way to avoid the issue, but the following function should fix it:

```
fixMesh[meshregion_] := Module[{meshpts, polys},
  meshpts = 
   Mean /@ Gather[MeshPrimitives[meshregion, 0][[;; , 1]], 
     Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^-5 &];
  polys = 
   Select[Polygon /@ 
     Map[First@Nearest[meshpts, #] &, 
      MeshPrimitives[meshregion, 2][[;; , 1]], {2}], 
    RegionMeasure[#] > 10^-8 &];
  DiscretizeGraphics[Graphics3D[polys]]
  ]
```

Then

```
fixMesh[surf]
```

will return the correct mesh region with no duplicated points.

**An explanation**

There are two steps in the `fixMesh` function. The first finds the "proper" vertices of the mesh. I have just taken the mean of all points deemed sufficiently close. There are certainly more accurate ways (there's no guarantee that this mean actually lies within the region being discretised, although it won't be out by very much), but it's nice and simple.

```
newmeshpts = Mean /@ Gather[MeshPrimitives[surf, 0][[;; , 1]], Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^-5 &];
Length@newmeshpts
```

> 10

The cut-off `10^-5` was chosen as the smallest threshold that yields the right number of points.

The second step is to replace all the vertices in the mesh polygons (`MeshPrimitives[surf, 2]`) by the `Nearest` corrected point in `newmeshpts`

```
newpolys = Polygon /@ 
  Map[First@Nearest[newmeshpts, #] &, MeshPrimitives[surf, 2][[;; , 1]], {2}]]
```

We're not done yet -- some of these polygons now have zero measure because all their vertices are the same point:

```
RegionMeasure /@ newpolys
```

> {0.122818, 0.177201, 0.122818, 0.378348, 0.37835, 0.378347, 0.177201,
>   0., 0.306921, 0.122818, 0.306922, 0.177201, 0., 0.436876, 0.306922,
>   0.43688, 1.86265*10^-9, 0., 0.436879, 0., 3.72529*10^-9}

So we just `Select` those with non-negligible measure:

```
newpolys = Select[newpolys, RegionMeasure[#] > 10^-8 &];
Length@newpolys
```

> 15

Now we have all our polygons, and just need to turn it back into a mesh. A simple way to do that is

```
newmesh = DiscretizeGraphics[Graphics3D[newpolys]]
```

[image]

Looks okay, but let's check

```
Length@MeshPrimitives[newmesh, 0]
Length@MeshPrimitives[newmesh, 2]
```

> 10
>
> 15

Comment: Many thanks, for the function and its expalnation. It works. Sometimes it required the proper tuning for the size of the Norm[..] and RegionMeasure[..], dependently on the particular mesh.

Comment: @sebqas I'm glad it works. Don't forget that you can [accept an answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if your question has been answered to your satisfaction.